# How to write a function including a "sigma" summation

Tags: python, numpy

I am analysing an electrical filter using SciPy's signal functions to plot a bode plot, step response. I want to plot a frequency response function for a square wave, according to this formula: [image: Fourier series]

This is my code so far:

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import control

#Values
R=25
C=400e-9
L=250e-3
resolution = 1000
periods = 10
n=10
T=1e-2 #10mS
t=np.linspace(0,1e-2*periods,resolution)

LTI = signal.lti([L,0],[R*C*L, L, R]) #defines the system with the transfer function

square = [1/2 + (2/np.pi*np.sin(2*np.pi/T*t)) + 2/(3*np.pi)*np.sin(6*np.pi/T*t) + 2/(5*np.pi)*np.sin(10*np.pi/T*t) + 2/(7*np.pi)*np.sin(14*np.pi/T*t) for t in t]

T, yout, xout = signal.lsim(LTI, square, t)

plt.plot(t, square)
plt.plot(T, yout)
plt.show()
```

How can I add more terms to the summation for `square` without having to write them out explicitly? For example, can I make it use a `k` variable to specify the number of terms?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't understand why there is a question, because you are **already using** the relevant technique in this code. (Hint: where the code says `... for t in t` at the end of the line calculating `square`, what do you suppose this means?) Also: please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. I [edit]ed the post to show how to ask questions directly and clearly, in the way we're looking for here - without irrelevant discussion.

Comment: (It's not immediately obvious to me why there are two different formulae in the image, or which one the code is supposed to implement.)

Comment: When `t` is a numpy array, np.sin(t) is also a numpy array. You don't need `for`-loop to calculate sin(t).